# How can I compile this basic Spring application without IDE?

Tags: java, compilation

This is my directory layout:

```
~ koraytugay$ ls -1 biz/tugay/hellospring/
Bike.java
Car.java
Vehicle.java
VehicleApp.java
VehicleService.java
beans.xml
```

So I am in the root folder and my .java files are in **biz/tugay/hellospring/**

Code for VehicleApp:

```
package biz.tugay.hellospring;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 29/06/15 Time: 15:16 */

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class VehicleApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext
                = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("biz/tugay/hellospring/beans.xml");
        VehicleService vehicleService = (VehicleService) applicationContext.getBean("vehicleService");
        vehicleService.driver();
    }

}
```

and VehicleService:

```
package biz.tugay.hellospring;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 29/06/15 Time: 15:10 */

public class VehicleService {

    private Vehicle vehicle;

    public void setVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }

    public void driver(){
        System.out.println(vehicle.drive());
    }

}
```

Also in my home directory I have the following jar files:

```
~ koraytugay$ ls -1 *.jar
spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
```

I tried several variations however I was not successful with any of them. One example:

```
~ koraytugay$ javac -cp .:/biz/tugay/hellospring biz/tugay/hellospring/VehicleApp.java
biz/tugay/hellospring/VehicleApp.java:4: error: package org.springframework.context does not exist
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
                                  ^
biz/tugay/hellospring/VehicleApp.java:5: error: package org.springframework.context.support does not exist
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
                                          ^
biz/tugay/hellospring/VehicleApp.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        ApplicationContext applicationContext
        ^
  symbol:   class ApplicationContext
  location: class VehicleApp
biz/tugay/hellospring/VehicleApp.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
                = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("biz/tugay/hellospring/beans.xml");
                      ^
  symbol:   class ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
  location: class VehicleApp
4 errors
```

I have the .jar files in the folder I am executing javac. Why the compiler is unable to find ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you either need to specify every jar

`java -cp ./spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar ; ./spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar ;./spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar ; ./spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar`

or use a wild card

`java -cp *.jar; /otherpath`

but thats only works with java 6 up

Comment: I tried like this but did not work: javac -cp *.jar;biz/tugay/hellospring;biz/tugay/hellospring/VehicleApp.java It says: -bash: biz/tugay/hellospring: is a directory
biz/tugay/hellospring/VehicleApp.java: line 1: package: command not found

Comment: try putting a trailing / on javac -cp *.jar;biz/tugay/hellospring/;biz/tugay/hellospring/VehicleApp.java

Comment: did not work again, it says: Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ javac -cp *.jar;biz/tugay/hellospring/;biz/tugay/hellospring/VehicleApp.java
javac: invalid flag: spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
-bash: biz/tugay/hellospring/: is a directory
biz/tugay/hellospring/VehicleApp.java: line 1: package: command not found

Comment: thats bash expanding up the wildcard in the classpath, try -cp "*.jar" so bash doesnt expand it, and javac gets it

Comment: you mean like this right: koraytugay$ javac -cp "*.jar";biz/tugay/hellospring/;biz/tugay/hellospring/VehicleApp.java ? This did not work either, same error..

Comment: try single quotes - bash will interpret double quotes

Comment: Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ javac -cp '*.jar';biz/tugay/hellospring/;biz/tugay/hellospring/VehicleApp.java
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
-bash: biz/tugay/hellospring/: is a directory
biz/tugay/hellospring/VehicleApp.java: line 1: package: command not found still no :)

Comment: I need to understand some very basic thing, do I need to compile and recompile every time I make some change to the source code? Is it possible to run the code interpretatively without compilation, because the compilation process takes some time. No way to simply run the code directly after modification like PHP?